# Bing News Search results from a particular website

Tags: azure, bing-api, bing-news-search-api

Is there an option in Bing Search to get search results from a particular news website?

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Custom Search API enables you to create tailored ad-free search experiences for topics that you care about. You can specify the domains and webpages for Bing to search.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-custom-search-api-v7-reference

you can use site parameter in API query to get results from specific website, but it;s not guranteed as advance search operators are no longer supported.
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=q=Trump+site:wikipedia.com